# Backbone collection empty when method called via change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Right off the bat: this is my first Backbone app so if there are any design flaws I'm all ears. The purpose of this app is to draw/re-draw a bar graph based upon changing input values.

Input values are stored in the `SliderModel`. Each `DataPoint` model in the `DataSeries` collection is supposed to reprent one column of data that gets drawn in the `BarGraph` view.

When the user changes values in the `SliderModel`, I've tied and event handler method in the `BarGraph` so that I can dynamically re-draw the graph according to the input.

When the page loads, the `updateCalculations` method in the `BarGraph` view is run. The calculations are processed correctly and the graph is drawn appropriately (all zeros).

However, once the user starts entering input (i.e. one single character) the `other` variable below (from `updateCalculations` method in the view) is evaluated as `undefined`

> var other = this.collection;

For some reason the `collection` in the `BarGraph` view is being cleared out when the `updateCalculations` method is called via a change to the `SliderModel` properties.

**Model**

Model containing default values and calculation methods

```
var SliderModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {

    },

    defaults: {
        purchasePayment: '0',
        fixedRate: '0',
        returnSpx: '0',
        slidervalue: '0'
    },

    fixedAllocation: function () {
        return this.attributes.purchasePayment * (1 - (this.attributes.slidervalue / 100));
    },

    illustratedEoy: function() {
        return this.fixedAllocation() * Math.pow(1 + (this.attributes.fixedRate / 100), 7);
    },

    eoyContractVal: function (value) {
        return this.illustratedEoy() + parseFloat(value);
    }
});
```

**Model/Collection**

Collection and model type of collection

```
var DataPoint = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function (lbl, ctrct, rtrn) {
        this.set({
            label: lbl,
            contract: ctrct,
            annReturn: rtrn
        })
    },
});

var DataSeries = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: DataPoint,

    fetch: function () {
        this.reset();
        this.add([
            new DataPoint("1/7yrs", "111830.17", "1.63%"),
            new DataPoint("2/7yrs", "115311.17", "2.07%"),
            new DataPoint("3/7yrs", "118984.65", "2.52%"),
            new DataPoint("4/7yrs", "122859.65", "2.98%"),
            new DataPoint("5/7yrs", "126947.77", "3.46%"),
            new DataPoint("6/7yrs", "131260.74", "3.94%"),
            new DataPoint("7/7yrs", "135810.92", "4.44%")
        ])
    }
});
```

**View**

The `SliderModel` is the model assigned to this view. The `DataSeries` is the collection assigned to the view.

```
var BarGraph = Backbone.View.extend({

    "el": "#graph",

    options: {barDemo: ""},

    initialize: function (options) {

        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.collection.bind("change", this.updateCollection);

        //Bind model change event to view event handler
        this.model.bind('change:purchasePayment', this.updateCollection);
        this.model.bind('change:slidervalue', this.updateCollection);
        this.model.bind('change:purchasePayment', this.updateCollection);
        this.model.bind('change:slidervalue', this.updateCollection);
        this.model.bind('change:fixedRate', this.updateCollection);
        this.model.bind('change:returnSpx', this.updateCollection);

        //Run setup methods
        this.drawGraph();
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.updateCollection();
    },

    drawGraph: function() {
        var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 };

        this.options.barDemo = d3.selectAll($(this.el)).append("svg:svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom + 20);
    },

    updateCollection: function () {
        var sum = 0.00;
        var that = this.model;

        //Collection shows as 'undefined' when this method is fired via change event
        var other = this.collection;

        var indexed = $.makeArray($('#IndexedTable').find('tbody tr'));

        var i = 0;
        this.collection.each(function (m) {
            var value = that.eoyContractVal(that.indexedIllustrated(i));
            sum = parseFloat(sum) + parseFloat(value);

            other.models[i].attributes.contract = value.toFixed(2);
            other.models[i].attributes.annReturn = that.annReturn(value).toFixed(2) + '%';
            i++;
        });

        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {

    },
});
```

**jQuery**

How the above code is initialized

```
var sliderModel = new SliderModel;
var dataSeries = new DataSeries();
new BarGraph({
    collection: dataSeries,
    model: sliderModel
});
```

Comment: i could not know why collection is undefined , but you have a turn around solution , you can access the collection from the model like that : var other = this.model.collection , otherwise if you can create a jsfiddle  , it makes it easy for us to see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all it's a bad bad idea overriding original Collection methods like fetch. You don't need that.

If you want to add some test data without going to the server, use the `reset` method or `add` like you did, outside of the collection definition.

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset

I would leave the collection with just the `model` attribute. In your "main" (your jQuery ready handler), fill the data:

```
var slider = new SliderModel();
var dataSeries = new DataSeries();
var view = new BarGraph({
  model: slider,
  collection: dataSeries
});


dataSeries.reset([
  new DataPoint("1/7yrs", "111830.17", "1.63%"),
  new DataPoint("2/7yrs", "115311.17", "2.07%"),
  new DataPoint("3/7yrs", "118984.65", "2.52%"),
  new DataPoint("4/7yrs", "122859.65", "2.98%"),
  new DataPoint("5/7yrs", "126947.77", "3.46%"),
  new DataPoint("6/7yrs", "131260.74", "3.94%"),
  new DataPoint("7/7yrs", "135810.92", "4.44%")
]);
```

Now in your View, you're listening to a `change` event in the collection, but that is a Model event.
http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Normally it's preferred to listen to the `reset` event, which you can trigger either resetting the collection by yourself, like we just did, or calling `collection.fetch({reset:true})` to get data from the server.

It's recommended practice to use the `listenTo` function for event handling, because it automatically binds the function context to the current object.
http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo

So your initialize method becomes:

```
initialize: function (options) {

  _.bindAll(this, "render");
  this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.updateCollection);

  //Bind model change event to view event handler
  //instead of individually listen to every attribute change
  //just listen to any change in one line
  this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.updateCollection);

  //Run setup methods
  this.drawGraph();
  //not needed with fake data... or save it to a JSON file and fetch it!
  //this.collection.fetch();
  this.updateCollection();
}
```

Comment: For his project I'm not going to need any server requests, just manipulating data on the page (it's a rate calculator). Being that's the case would I want to simply set the fetch method to first call `this.reset()` and then add 5 blank `DataPoints` to the collection or is there a cleaner/better practice method?

Comment: But the point is, why rewrite a method? It already exists and it's called `reset`, as my code shows. Did you try it?

Comment: I think maybe I don't fully understand what is involved in the `reset` then. Doesn't it clear out the collection so it has a total Model count of 0?

Comment: Yes, but you can also add new models as shown in my example.